# An efficient way to sort complex numbers by their euclidean distances in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, sorting

I have several complex numbers that I need to sort by their euclidean distances. I solve this problem like this:

```
            # A1x = Lowest Point (LP)
            # B1x = Point 1 (P1)
            # B4x = Point 2 (P2)

            C1 = euclidean(A1x, B1x) # Build the distance between LP and P1
            C4 = euclidean(A1x, B4x) # Build the distance between LP and P2

            array = np.array([C1, C4]) # Put the distances into an array...
            array.sort() # ...and sort it.

            # If the the distance between LP and P1 is the first element in the array
            # then take P1 as y_max value etc.

            if C1 == array[0]: 
                y_max = B1x

                if C4 == array[1]:
                    y_min = B4x

            if C4 == array[0]:
                y_max = B4x

                if C1 == array[1]:
                    y_min = B1x
```

This way works well for three or four points. However, now I got eight or nine points and the way as stated above gets a little bit nasty because I have to write the if conditions for every single point. Therefore, I would like to ask you if you know a better way to sort the complex numbers by their euclidean distances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `argsort`, this is straightforward:

```
Ap = np.array([1, 2]) # "lowest point"
B = np.array([[0,0], [1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4]]) # sample array of points
dist = np.linalg.norm(B - Ap, ord=2, axis=1) # calculate Euclidean distance (2-norm of difference vectors)
sorted_B = B[np.argsort(dist)]
```

`sorted_B` ends up containing the points of list B, but in sorted order by Euclidean distance to the point Ap. For the above input, you'd get the output

```
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [0, 0],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4]])
```

Note that using NumPy functions this way should be faster and more efficient than using the equivalent Python function `list.sort`.

Comment: At first, I'm so sorry for my delayed reply! My problem with this methods was that I can´t put the different arrays in one array "B" like in your example. However, the lines "dist = np.linalg.norm(B - Ap, ord=2, axis=1)"
and "sorted_B = B[np.argsort(dist)]" set me on the right path. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

```
from functools import partial

complex_number_list.sort(key=partial(euclidean, A1x))
```

You can also use `abs` instead of `euclidean`.

Comment: `key` should be a one argument function. `euclidean()` as given above has two arguments.

Comment: Hello Alex, sorry for my delayed reply. At first I have to check out the partial module to understand how this code works. However, your code looks very efficient and clean. I will reply as fast as I can. Thank you very much!